# Intents directory and how to use it

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello I'm a new to programming and I trying to find out how does intent defined its directory (how android knows what is the extras to put in it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you start here:

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

(Specifically) http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Or pick up "Beginning Android":

[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Android-Experts-Voice-Source/dp/1430224193](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224193)

Google offers a fantastic set of tutorials.  You should use them :)

Comment: My original answer stands.  There's no such thing as an intents directory and you certainly can't write it.  Intents, extras, et al. are included in those links.